# Wget with input file says "No such file or directory"

Tags: wget

I want to use Wget for Windows to retrieve some files on URL's which I have specified in a file called `WgetInput.txt`

After reading the documentation I figured out the command I should use, which is:

`wget --no-cache -o WgetLogFile.txt -i "./WgetInputFile.txt" --random-wait`

However, when running this command from the Command Prompt I get the following message in the logfile:

> WgetInputFile.txt: No such file or directory
>
> Geen URL's gevonden in WgetInputFile.txt. (*translated: No URL's found in WgetInputFile.txt*)

I figured it might have something to do with the path, but specifying the full path did not help. Also removing the path altogether didn't help.

Because this didn't help, I installed Cygwin and tried the command from over there, but this only resulted in the same error message.

All input and output files are present in the folder `D:\Temp2\WGet`.

The Wget application is added to the %path% environment variable.

Because I can't find any results on Google with this issue, I'm guessing it has to be someting obvious.

Comment: Is the input file `WgetInput.txt` or `WgetInputFile.txt`?  Look at the input file names carefully you've mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oh, I feel rather stupid now! This was indeed the issue. Sometimes you just stare at a single line and don't see these differences anymore. Thanks for being my....eh...rubber duck.